# JavaFX Window setOnShown() vs setOnShowing()

Tags: java, javafx-8, desktop-application

I've started working on a JavaFX desktop application since a few months. While going through window events, i came across these 2 types of event settings, `setOnShown()` and `setOnShowing()` for the `Window` (or child `Stage`) class. Similar are the methods for hiding the window. I also know that one is supposed to fire while showing window and one is supposed to fire when it is shown. Now i want to ask:

1. What exactly is the reason for having these two events separate ? wasn't setOnShowing() enough ?
2. If the window i'm trying to open makes a database call to populate a table in it every time it is opened, which event should i go with in this scenario ?

question might seem silly but please be patient before hitting down vote.

Comment: `WINDOW_SHOWING` → "_This event occurs on window **just before** it is shown_". `WINDOW_SHOWN` → "_This event occurs on window **just after** it is shown_". That's why they're separate events because they occur at different moments in the life-cycle. Same for the hiding/hidden event types.

Comment: Life-cycle, right I understand.But what if my window and it's nodes are to be programmatically generated and i put database call to fetch records in the `WINDOW_SHOWING` event, wouldn't that affect performance since the JVM might be rendering nodes and calling the db (because of window showing event) at the same time if i'm not mistaken? should i call the db while showing or after showing the window?

Comment: Regardless of what (not necessarily window-related) event you use to trigger it, the database call should not be done on the _JavaFX Application Thread_.

Comment: Right, i got it.